# How would you call someone that connects two people together?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an English term to describe someone that acts as a "mediator" between two people, i.e someone that connects two people together?

Comment: I think you would get the best answer if you provided an example of the usage you're thinking of so as to give context. e.g. "The two lovers were originally brought together by a mediator"

Comment: What's wrong with *mediator*?

Comment: Yenta or yenteh.

Comment: Generally *mediator* is related to resolving a conflict or misunderstanding. More context is needed.

Comment: Hi, every so often I go through posts which have "How do you call....?" or "How are ______ called?"  in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing your title to *“**What** would you call someone...?”* Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several words that may be suitable, depending on the context: *go-between, intermediary, agent, medium, broker, factor, dealer, liaison, middleman*.

Comment: Can I use broker for someone who connects two unknown people together (and therefore become friends)?

Comment: @Tom Do you mean a *matchmaker*, perhaps?

Comment: No, Tom, not for that. In that case, I'm not sure there is a single word. A _matchmaker_ is someone who brings two people together, usually for the purpose of matrimony, and perhaps sometimes even for money.

Comment: In other situations, one might still use the word _matchmaker_, but perhaps in scare-quotes, or with enough context, to show a non-standard (but fairly clear) usage: 'She's good at bringing together people she thinks will get on well with each other - quite the matchmaker!'

Comment: I second Barrie. We've to also check under what context it is used.

Answer (score 1):

The term "**marriage broker**" does in fact exist. The modern day version of the *matchmaker*, this agent usually works for an online international marriage agency. A marriage broker helps arrange marriages between two strangers, who are usually living in two different countries, for a sum of money. Also called a "matcher".

Comment: I like "matcher". Thanks @Mari-Lou A

Answer (score 0):

Mutual friend / acquaintance / colleague / etc.: "A mutual friend put us in touch."